# AngularJS ngAnimate firing too soon

Tags: javascript, angularjs

At the moment p2 will animate in as p1 is animating out, then p1 will be removed and p2 will glitch up the page. Obviously the desired effect would be 1 fades out then 2 fades in.

**html:**

```
 <nav>
    <a ng-click="changeView('p1')">p1</a>
    <a ng-click="changeView('p2')">p2</a>
 </nav>
 <div ng-view class="page">
 </div>
```

**css:**

```
.page {
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:#eee;
    transition:all 1s linear;
}

.page.ng-enter {
    -webkit-opacity:0;
    opacity:0;
}

.page.ng-enter-active {
    -webkit-opacity:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.page.ng-leave {
    -webkit-opacity:0;
    opacity:0;
}

.page.ng-leave-active {
    -webkit-opacity:1;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Is there a standard way to achieve this? I've tried using `ng-enter-stagger` as recommended by yearofmoo but still no dice.

Comment: You probably want to add position:absolute to the ng-enter, ng-leave, ng-enter-active, and ng-leave-active styles. you probably want to use transition:all 1s ease rather than linear as well. If you post a plunker with your templates I can help more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of transitioning, try an animation with a delay until 50%. On SASS, it might look like:

```
// Keyframes, could be regular CSS but I've already got a SASS snippet
+keyframes( myOut )
  0%
    +opacity( 1 )
  50%, 100%
    +opacity( 0 )


+keyframes( myIn )
  0%, 50%
    +opacity( 0 )
  100%
    +opacity( 1 )

// Add classes
.page.ng-enter-active
    +animation( myIn 1s 1 )

.page.ng-leave-active
    +animation( myOut 1s 1 )
```